# Accents on Mazurka (Marieta by Francisco Tarrega)

Tags: classical-guitar, accent

I'm practicing on Marieta by Francisco Tarrega (Mazurka in a-moll) 
My question is how should I accent the beats?
I mean on what tone?
I mean it's not like waltzes (ONE two three) so how's it?
I have listened to Chopin's Mazurkas a lot, but I can't make that on this song. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Wikipedia,

> The mazurka (in Polish mazurek, plural mazurki) is a Polish folk dance
>   in triple meter, usually at a lively tempo, and with "strong accents
>   unsystematically placed on the second or third beat".

My suggestion, then, is to listen to a recording or two (there are dozens on youtube.com) and try to pick up the beat patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The scores at IMSLP have accents marked.

http://imslp.org/wiki/Marieta_(T%C3%A1rrega%2C_Francisco)

Comment: So they do, but are these the original markings or the publisher's editor's markings?

Comment: All 3 scores seem to have the same dynamic marks, which might suggest they are not editorial. In any case, the OP's question is "how to play the piece" not "what was marked in the composer's manuscript" - those two things are often different in any musical genre.